# Pythonのsqlite3モジュールでWITH句を使うとエラーになる

Tags: python, sqlite

WITH句を使った以下のようなSQLをSQLite3で実行すると、正常に実行できます。

```sql
WITH order_3 AS 
(
    SELECT
     item_id
    FROM
      order
    WHERE
     ordernum >= 3
)
SELECT
  i.itemcode,
  i.itemname,
  i.price
FROM
  items AS i
  JOIN order_3 as o ON o.item_id = i.id
ORDER BY
 i.itemcode ASC
```

このSQLをPython3のsqliteモジュールを使って、以下のようなプログラムを実行するとSyntaxErrorになってしまいます。

```py
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect("hoge.sqlite3")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Pythonのsqlite3は、WITH句の実行をサポートしていないんでしょうか・・・？

Comment: `order` という名前のテーブルがありますが、`order` は予約語なので(`order by`)ダブルクォートかバッククォートで囲む必要があります。でもまぁ、テーブル名を変更した方が良いかと思いますが…

Comment: [Release History Of SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html)によると2014-02-03 (3.8.3)からサポートしているようです。(最新は2019-10-10 (3.30.1)) [Why can't I use WITH statement in sqlite3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27539139/9014308), [Error using SQL 'With' clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24036310/9014308), [Python sqlite3 version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1553160/9014308)